# How to compute an adjacency matrix?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm doing graph theory in my discrete math class, and I'm not understanding the concept. I've read online it has something to do with number of edges for undirected and number of arrows for directed, but it's kind of confusing.

Comment: You don't "compute" it -- you just write it down. Put a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ of the matrix if there's an edge from node $i$ to node $j$, and $0$ otherwise. (Or possibly the other way around, if the graph is directed; conventions differ).

Comment: Thank you. Completely understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the adjacency matrix of a graph G is defined as a matrix A of dimension $n \times n$ and each component is

$[A(G)]_{i,j}$ = $a_{i,j}$ = $\begin{cases}1 \text{  if }(v_{i},v_{j}) \in E\\ 0 \text{  otherwise}\end{cases}$

where $(v_{i},v_{j})$ is an arc of the graph. So, the adjacency matrix has a 1 on an element if there exists the corresponding arc on the graph G. Does it make sense?

Comment: $A$ doesn't need to be symmetric for directed graphs.

Comment: I was describing the most general case, and you will find by yourself that in a directed graph A doesn't need to be symmetric ;)

Comment: No, actually I don't think you did. In the most general case, $A$ is not symmetric - contrary to what your wrote in `$G$ is defined as a symmetric matrix A`. You are right that by computing the components as you wrote, one will quickly find that this is not true. But this doesn't make it less wrong in my opinion. In the end I'm just nagging, but I thought it might be worth pointing out.

Comment: I did now ;) is it ok? Anything else to check? ;)

Comment: Indeed, I was about to provide suggestions for how to improve the answer for OP (answer the part about number of edges/arrows (=$n$), add example graph with example matrix, ...), but OP's "completely understand now"-comment above somehow stopped my over-enthusiasm and I guess we can let this (perfectly fine) answer be as it is. :)

Comment: I didn't figure out what OP is, though :) but in any case, I think this is fine for now. Let's wait for who asked, if there is something else which is not clear  ;) Did my comment "stopped your over.enthusiasm"? You probably misunderstood its meaning ;)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. OP = original poster. So no, not *your* comment stopped further suggestions but the [comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527451/how-to-compute-an-adjacency-matrix/1527467?noredirect=1#comment3110659_1527451) *by the author* of the question that said that everything is clear now made any further efforts non-necessary.